# Area of a random square with uniform sides

Tags: probability, statistics

Suppose a random square has a side length that is uniform on $[0, 1]$. What is the expected area?

My solution was to say that once I know the side, I know the area since I just have to square it. Therefore, assuming $X$ is the length of one side, it is:

$$E[X] =\int_0^1xdx = 1/2$$

Square that to get $1/4$. However, the answer I was given is $1/3$ because, if $X$ is as before, the area is $X^2$, and so

$$E[X^2] = \int_0^1x^2dx = 1/3$$

Both approaches make sense to me, yet the answer is clearly different. What am I missing?

Comment: The answer, almost by definition, is $E(X^2)$.

Comment: use the definition of expected value.

Comment: Your first approach says in effect that $E(X^2)=E(X)^2$, which is not true.

Comment: The median area would be $\dfrac14$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\def\fr#1#2{{\textstyle{\frac{#1}{#2}}}}$The area could be anything from $0$ to $1$, but the "probability" (more accurately: probability density) of getting a small area is not the same as the probability of getting a large area.  This is why your first approach is wrong.

To give a specific example, consider the smallest and largest quarter of the possible areas:
$$P(A<\fr{1}{4})=P(X<\fr{1}{2})=\fr{1}{2}\ ,$$
while
$$P(A>\fr{3}{4})=P(X>\fr{\sqrt3}{2})=1-\fr{\sqrt3}{2}\ne\fr{1}{2}\ .$$

Comment: Is it correct to say that the distribution of the areas is denser at the low end, since it's more probable you will get a smaller area (because you are squaring a number between 0 and 1) than a larger area?

Comment: I'm not quite sure I understand how you are using the word "denser", I would have said it was the other way round: the lowest quarter of the areas come from $50$% of the $X$ values, while the highest quarter come from about $13$% of the $X$ values.

Comment: OK thanks got it! It's pretty much what I thought, but I expressed myself wrong (and got the numbers mixed up).

Answer (score 1):

The side length $X \sim {\rm Uniform}(0,1)$ has an average length ${\rm E}[X] = 1/2$ as you pointed out, but **the square of the mean is not necessarily equivalent to the mean of the square**.  That is to say, $${\rm E}[X]^2 \ne {\rm E}[X^2],$$ and for a general function $g$ of a random variable $X$, $$g({\rm E}[X]) \ne {\rm E}[g(X)].$$  To understand why, think of a situation where the square's side length is not drawn from a continuous uniform distribution, but rather, a discrete uniform distribution on $\{1, 2\}$.  That is to say, the square has a side length of $1$ or $2$ with equal probability $1/2$.  Then the expected value of the side length is of course $3/2$, but as the only possibilities for the square's area are $1$ and $4$, the expected value of the area is $\frac{1+4}{2} = \frac{5}{2} \ne (\frac{3}{2})^2 = \frac{9}{4}$.  This is because, in general, $$\left(\frac{a+b}{2}\right)^2 \ne \frac{a^2 + b^2}{2},$$ and in the general discrete case, $$\left( \frac{x_1 + x_2 + \cdots + x_n}{n} \right)^2 \ne \frac{x_1^2 + x_2^2 + \cdots + x_n^2}{n}.$$  For your continuous uniform case, then, the first integral corresponds to ${\rm E}[X]^2$, whereas the second (correct) integral is ${\rm E}[X^2]$, the expected value of the *area*.